# How to make layer disappear in slider revolution?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider

I am using slider revolution with wordpress.

I would like to know i can make the layer disappear after 4 second.

Thanks

Comment: Which layout? kindly explain in details

Comment: Please provide some code or further details about your request, the more informations you give us, the easily we will be able to help you

Comment: I meant layer, sorry. Slider revolution is a built in slider used for wordpress. A layer may be a text or an image that is used as slide.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the answer below worked?

Comment: yes . thank you. it works in case of  one slider.

Comment: that's good, please, mark the answer as solved click on tick mark ( right ) it will help others

Comment: You can repeat revapi22.revremoveslide(1); as many time you want using 1,2,3,4 [ id's of slides ], actually answer solves the issues in question, you are changing the scenario, if you asked for multiple slides then there is also a solution, anyway it's your choice to revoke the right answer for asked question

Comment: if repeating revapi22.revremoveslide(1);  does not work you can repeat whole function, you have to appreciate others efforts in answering, anyway good to know it's solved

Answer (score 1):

**Tested on live environment and its working**

Use revolution slider api

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  revapi22.revremoveslide(1); // 1 = your slide ID
  console.log('slide removed')
}, 4000);
```

Add this code under slider settings > Custom JS, check what will come in the place of `revapi22` for you in slider settings > API Functions